# Javascript filter elements from array which holds elements together from another array

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have two arrays. One like `first = ['a','b','c']` the other like `second = ['acd','abd', 'gfa', 'kqb']`. What I want to do is a function to return elements from the second array where elements from the first array occur together.

For example, the function will return ['acd','abd'] because those are the only elements in the second array where the elements from the first array occur together. I need it in javascript/typescript.

Comment: First off, what have you tried?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean by "occur together"?  Is it that the count of characters in an element that occur in the first array is greater than 1?  Something else?

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes that is what I mean

Comment: Okay, then, what have you tried so far?  StackOverflow is designed to help you with coding questions, but not to write your code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does what you need:

```js
first = ['a','b','c'];
second = ['acd','abd', 'gfa', 'kqb'];

function findOccurencies(first, second) {
  const result = [];
  second.forEach(target => {
    let count = 0;
    first.forEach(source => {
      count += target.indexOf(source) >= 0 ? 1 : 0;
    });
    if (count >= 2) {
      result.push(target);
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(findOccurencies(first, second));
```

Comment: I believe using the `es6` `filter` method is a more idiomatic and simplified approach (my answer below).

Comment: I agree, `es6` `filter` is better. This solution just was the first that came to my mind

Answer (score 4):

(Please do look at how to improve your question as mentioned in the comments.  But as someone has already posted code here, and I like my solution better, here it is.)

Here is one approach:

```js
const foo = (arr1, arr2) => arr2.filter(str => arr1.reduce(
  (count, char) => count + (str.includes(char) ? 1 : 0), 
  0 
) > 1)

const result = foo(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['abc', 'abd', 'gfa', 'kqb'])

console.log(result)
```

There is a likely inefficiency here, in that it continues looping over the first array even after passing two matches.  This would partially alleviate that, if it turned out to be a problem:

```
  (count, char) => count > 1 ? count : count + (str.includes(char) ? 1 : 0),
```

This still loops, but no longer does the expensive `includes` call once the threshold has been reached.  If you wanted to stop the looping altogether, you'd probably have to use a more imperative approach, such as a `for`-loop.

Comment: `reduce` is certainly another way to approach this problem. I would personally simplify the arithmetic expression by coercing the boolean to a number using the unary operator: `+str.includes(char) + count`

Comment: @Andi: I generally avoid such coercion.  But that does make me realize that this would be cleaner than what I wrote: `(count, char) => str.includes(char) ? count + 1 : count`,

Comment: Why would you avoid this type of explicit type coercion?

Comment: For the record, I believe `reduce` is more performant than my solution which uses nested `filter` methods: http://jsben.ch/HJU3X

Comment: @Andi: because booleans are not number, nor do they hold numbers; I don't like the arbitrary mapping.  I have no issue with `Number('123') //=> 123`, as that seems logical, but I find `+myBoolean` to be hard to explain  It's not worth it to me.

Comment: @Andi: if the difference in speed here is important, then this should already probably be written directly with a `for` or `while` loop.

Comment: That makes sense – better to be explicit than implicit or subtle. Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably approach it like this:

```js
const first = ['a','b','c'];
const second = ['acd','abd', 'gfa', 'kqb'];

const result = second.filter(
    word => first.filter(char => word.includes(char)).length > 1
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way... not elegant, but i think it gets the job done...

```
const first = ['a','b','c']
const second = ['acd','abd', 'gfa', 'kqb']

let validated = []
second.forEach(z=>{
  for(let m = 0; m<=z.length-1; m++){
    let q = first.includes(z[m])
    validated.push(q)
  }
  let count = 0;
  validated.forEach((e,i)=>{
    if(e){
        if(validated[i-1] || validated === []){
            count++;
        }
    }
  })
  validated = []
  if(count !== 0){console.log(z)}
})
```